# Mime type audio not working properly Laravel

Tags: laravel

Hi there I have this validation:

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'audio'  => 'max:3072 |mimes:audio/mp3',
        ];
    }
```

And I upload an audio which is 1mb and its mp3 type, but it shows me the

```
The audio must be a file of type: audio/mp3 .
```

Instead of passing through the validation. 
I tried  `'audio'  => 'mimes:audio/mp3 |max:3072',`
also `'audio'  => 'mimes:mp3 |max:3072'`,
But still nothing, and when I try to upload a bigger audio for examplee 4 mb it shows me the size validation which is fine. Can someone help me what is it that I am doing wrong here..?!

Comment: Does the validation error also show what mime the file is getting detected as?

Comment: Also, try `audio/mpeg`

Comment: no I did not added that part that shows what mime file is detected

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but solved it by using "mpga" mime to validate mp3 file

```
'audio' => 'mimes:mpga',
```

This happens because Laravel uses guessExtension() method to get file extension, if we use that method on file that we want to validate:

```
var_dump($request->file('audio')->guessExtension());
```

we see that the output of guessExtension() would be mpga for mp3 file so we can use mpga mime to validate a mp3 file.

Answer (score 0):

visit this http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types

and try  'audio'  => 'max:3072|mimes:audio/mpeg',

Answer (score 0):

try this once
'audio'  => 'max:3072 |mimetypes:audio/mp3',

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $this->validate($request, [
        'file_mp3' => ['required', function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            if ($value->getClientOriginalExtension() != 'mp3') {
                $fail(':attribute must be .mp3!');
            }

        }]
    ]);
```